# stop asp.net postback when UseSubmitBehavior="false"

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net button with UseSubmitBehavior="false"  like this:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"    OnClientClick="if (!LoginPopup()) {return false;}" CssClass="login-button" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster, Login %>"> </asp:Button>
```

and js function like this:

```
 function LoginPopup() {       
        var username = $("#<%= UsernameTextBox.ClientID %>").val();
        var password = $("#<%= PasswordTextBox.ClientID %>").val();
        var remMe;
        if ($('#<%= chkRememberMe.ClientID %>').attr('checked') == "checked") {
            remMe = true;
        }
        else {
            remMe = false;
        }

        if (username != '' && password != '')
            CallPageMethod("LoginPopup", ["username", username, "password", password, "rememberMe", remMe], LoginPopupSucceeded, LoginPopupFailed);
        else
            alert("Invalid username/password");
            return false;
    }
```

and I call it on keypress of textboxes like this:

```
   $("#<%=this.UsernameTextBox.ClientID%>").keypress(function (event) {
           fireButtonClick($("#<%=this.btnLogin.ClientID%>"), event);
        });



 function fireButtonClick(ctrl, event) {
        if (event.which || event.keyCode) {
            if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {
                ctrl.click();
                return false;
            }
```

I want to stop postback when input is invalid but It is not working. Please suggest me how to stop postback

Comment: Page is doing postback means your javascript code is wrong. Have u tried to find it out where u r getting error???

Comment: yes when UseSubmitBehavior="false" is added to asp.net button then _doPostback() is automatically added to button.

Comment: Do you really need to have `UseSubmitBehavior`? You can get rid of that and explicitly define `OnClick`. `OnClick` won't fire unless `OnClientClick` returns true.

Comment: **return LoginPopup();** try this instead **OnClientClick="if (!LoginPopup()) {return false;}"**

Comment: still it does postback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem is the same I have.
Inside updatepanel when i put UseSubmitBehavior=false the page makes postback.

So I put one defaultbutton in panel, like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" defaultbutton="btnDisableEnter"> 
<ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnDisableEnter" runat="server" Text="fake button" OnClientClick="return false;" style="display:none;"/>
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

When UseSubmitBehavior="false" is added to ASP.NET button then __doPostback('btnLogin','') is automatically added to onclick event after your OnClientClick definition, so avoid __doPostback side server you must add return like that

> <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
> OnClientClick="if (!LoginPopup()) {return false;} return;"
> CssClass="login-button" Text="<%$ Resources: HRGELoggedOutMaster,
> Login %>"> </asp:Button>